# Issue using DOM in external javascript file / django

Tags: javascript, django, dom

So I'm toying around with django, html and javascript for the first time, writing an script to display an updating counter on the page. I had it working when just using text and without using the DOM. I decided to update it to use images instead but I can't get it to work.

Below is the html for displaying the initial duration / counter.

```
{% extends 'vices/index.html' %}
{% block content %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/js/clock.js"> </script>

<body onLoad="duration()">
<img src="/site_media/images/clock/0.jpg" id="second_1"/>
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the javascript function that I'm calling. For testing purposes I just want it to set the src to a specified different value.

```
function duration()
{
    //Irrelevant logic (works prior to attempting to import images)

    document.getElementById("second_1").src = "/site_media/images/clock/1.jpg"
    setTimeout("duration()",1000)

}
```

When I embed the javascript into the html file it seems to update properly, but when I pull all of the javascript to an external file I can't seem to get it to change the image.

Is there some crucial thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `{% block content %}` duplicating the `<body>` element?  Typically an outer template like `index.html` already contains its own body, which leads me to wonder if your `onLoad` is ever being called.

Comment: The 'onLoad' method was being called fine prior to using images / DOM and I haven't made any changes to index.html since then.

Comment: Looks like you were right, onLoad is not being called. I tested out just using a button with onclick being set to duration() and the change happened fine. Now I need to figure out why it's not being called. I went ahead and changed the <body> tag to <div> and nothing changed.

Comment: Wow I feel insanely dumb. I was creating an array incorrectly elsewhere in the file. Thanks for pointing out the onLoad not being called!